# Constant div size when minimizing browser window

Tags: html, css

I give my `div` elements sizes in `%` because I want them to be able to adapt to different screen sizes of different devices. I however want the size to be constant for a device. For example if a `div` is 60% in width of my laptop browser screen it should stay 60% even when I minimize size of my browser window.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: For this to achieve you need fixed widths in combination with media queries.

Comment: "*... if a div is 60% in width of my laptop browser screen it should stay 60% even when I minimize ...*": It **will** stay 60%. It won't  become 40% or 70%, will it?

Comment: it becomes 60% of the new window size after minimizing @abhitalks

Answer (score 1):

You are probally looking for

```
min-width: 800px;
```

If the width gets under 800px now the div wont resize smaller and just stay at this width.

Just make sure you add a media query like this:

```
div{
  width: 60%;
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  div{
    min-width: 800px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  div{
    min-width: 400px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure you create some media-queries, otherwise it will also be at least 800 px wide on mobiles!

Comment: @Rvervuurt: Not required because the Op "*wants*" it to stay at a size.

Comment: @abhitalks on devices where you can resize the window, yes. You most likely can't resize on mobile devices and therefore want to keep the `width: 60%` and no `min-width`. But then again, he didn't mention this clearly, so it might be true what you say :)

Comment: Great! Now we have a complete answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using % you can make the div adaptive, but inside side the div if there any image or fixed width elements it will not be adaptive, you need to make them adaptive using  media queries

ex:

```
/* Small Mobile Devices ( < 768px ) Style Begin */
 @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {

   .div-elements-name {
   width:100%;
}

}
```